# how to prompt message on link using jquery in zf?

Tags: jquery, zend-framework

I am beginner to Zf and dont know how to add jquery file in zf and want to prompt messsage on delete link using jquery in zf.

please help Me.
Thank you

Comment: Read some tutorials about Zend and how to use its templates. You have to put it there, since jQuery is client side, not server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Zend Framework 1 you would add the link to either local jQuery resource or CDN version in the layout.phtml file.  If you only want to intercept on a delete link for certain pages/ controller actions, you would add it in the particular actions view script.  Alternatively you could reference that code in the header of the layout.phtml file too.

Comment: I only want to delete a row in ddbtable on delete link but dont have jquery code. Can you please provide jquery code to prompt dialogue box on click of link. Thank You.

Comment: Have a look at and then the documentation for jQuery and zendhttp://jsfiddle.net/wG4gE/1/

Comment: but I want to delete data row of database and It's now headache to display jquery in Zf.

Comment: I have go through  it but it's not working in my prg

Comment: I won't be giving you any more help without you showing more effort and code.  Your last comment is a waste of time and insulting to be honest!

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false });


$('.button').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});

Comment: Come on man, get real.  That's only half the code!   Make a jsfiddle.net or something

Comment: show me a simple jsfiddle.net where that doesn't work.

Comment: Now I am getting dialogue box but the problem is it's clicking "Delete button itself" and hide dialogue box. Any solution? This is my code :

Comment: $(".deleteLink").click(function () {
                   $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                   });

                           $(function () {
                               $("#dialog").dialog({
                                   autoOpen: false,
                                   modal: true,
                                   dialogClass:"no-close",
                                    buttons: [
    {
      text: "OK",
      click: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "open" );
      }
    }
  ]

Comment: Yes, you're using `.click` instead of `$(".deleteLink").on('click', function(event){...` which is triggering the click rather than listening to it.

Comment: I used the way denoted,but still whn dialog box prompts,it delete all item of row without asking yes or know. If U can help me in,how to trigger action of zf on click of Yes button of dialog box. Please..and Thank You :)

Comment: In the `OK` button click function you are opening the same dialog.  You should make an ajax call to the ZF controller/action to instruct the deletion only when they click `OK`

Comment: Yes..by using ajax but can You provide some links for ajax as am completely new to Ajax. Thank You :)

Comment: No!  Google has links! More than I do!